# "used for variations" switch programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There are 860+ products with different variations. The task is to allow user bulk edit "used for variations" field for some attributes. For example, we have size, gender that is still needed for variations, but also we have material, that is needed for filters only, so deleting this attribute is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Totally untested and not particularly ideal if you have a lot of products as it could time out, but theoretically you could loop through all the variable products and update the `_product_attributes` meta value. I highly suggest you have a data backup and/or do this is a staging site.

```
function so_41978670_run_once(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'variable',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $products->have_posts() ){
        while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
            $products->the_post();
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            
            $attributes  = $product->get_attributes();
            $meta_values = array();

            if ( $attributes ) {
                foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_key => $attribute ) {

                    if( in_array( $attribute_key, array( 'size', 'gender' ) ) ){
                        // Modify the attributes meta.
                        $attributes[ $attribute_key ]['is_variation'] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_product_attributes', $attributes );

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Potential update for WooCommerce 3.0 CRUD functions, but still untested:

```
function so_41978670_run_once() {

    $args = array(
        'limit' => -1, 
        'type' => 'variable',
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
    if( ! empty ( $products ) ) {
        foreach ( $products as $product ) {

            $attributes  = $product->get_attributes();

            if ( $attributes ) {
                foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_key => $attribute ) {
                    if( in_array( $attribute_key, array( 'size', 'gender' ) ) ){
                        // Modify the attribute settings.
                        $attribute->set_variation( true );                        
                    }
                }
            }

            $product->set_attributes( $attributes );
            $product->save();

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'so_41978670_run_once' );
```

Comment: after 'posts_per_page' => -1  need comma, and is not working? nice idea. thanks

Comment: Good catch. It is untested as noted. If doing again, I would probably use the CRUD methods for interfacing with attributes.

Comment: CRUD you mean from database mysql? yeah I try run this function on init but nothing change :(

Comment: no, I mean using the product getters and setters added in WooCommerce 3.0. I would no longer try to use `update_post_meta()`. I'd use `wc_get_products()` and then looping through the returned product objects... I'd use [`$product->set_attributes( $attributes )`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0db54ecec3284d027caf171a9880e1c28451259b/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1107) and then `$product->save()`. That let's WooCommerce worry about the meta key and how the data is formatted.

Comment: Check my edit, but unfortunately... it's still untested.

Comment: HI thanks,  if( ! empty ( $products ))

need extra ), I try execute this but nothing change.. I will keep trying. thanks _/\_

Comment: You may be at a point where you need to open a new question. Did you note that my code is (in theory) only going to effect the size and gender attributes? I'd try stepping through it to see where it's getting stuck.